# How much data do I have on my S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can we find out how much data one have in totality of all the buckets in AWS S3?

There are a lot of buckets, so calculating size of each bucket and then adding them up to find the total size of data is a lot of math.

Is there a smarter way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the AWS CLI or a package. Already been answered on a different site: [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/84815/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-amazon-s3-bucket)

```
 aws s3api list-objects --bucket BUCKETNAME --output json --query "[sum(Contents[].Size), length(Contents[])]"
```

Or use ncdu-s3, has great documentation on usage and installation, [link here](https://github.com/EverythingMe/ncdu-s3).

Comment: I don't need an individual breakdown of each buckets. 
I am trying to find-out total storage on our S3.

Comment: the aws s3api command results in `Illegal token value '(Contents[].Size), length(Contents[])]`

Answer (score 0):

Look at your bill.

You should have a breakdown of the total amount of storage used by region and storage type.

There is also S3 Inventory, which requires some set up, but will give you a breakdown by bucket.

Finally, there are also 3rd party products what will do this for you.

Comment: I am part of consolidated billing, the AWS billing dashboard is not very efficient then.

Comment: Even i you are part of a consolidated billing ogainization, each linked account still provides individual bills. You can also turn on detailed billing, and create a report for just your usage.